Is there any way to add a effect on a widget on hover in flutter
I dont want to use the WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith function to resolve it.
i cant find any thing online . please help me in finding a solution to the problem. Is there any way to add a effect on a widget on hover in flutter

You can use the MouseRegion widget. The onHover callback triggers once, when a pointer moves into a position. The onExit triggers when the mouse pointer exited the widget, and it's still mounted. Start the effect on onHover, and stop it when onExit triggers.

Using Inkwell You can add hover,
Example:
InkWell(
  onTap: () => null,
  onHover: (hovering) {
    // Handle hover state (e.g., change color, size, etc.)
    // Set a boolean variable to track whether the mouse is hovering.
  },
  child: const Text(
    'Hello, world',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
  ),
)

or can be used MouseRegion
Eg:
MouseRegion(
  onEnter: (_) {
    // Handle mouse enter (hover start)
  },
  onExit: (_) {
    // Handle mouse exit (hover end)
  },
  child: YourWidget(),
)

I hope this may help you to solve it,

You can wrap the widget that is supposed to respond to mouse hovering with MouseRegion widget as follows:
MouseRegion(
        onHover: (hoverEvent){
          // mouse pointer entered widget scope
        },
        onExit: (event){
         // do what you want, mouse exits the widget scope
        },
        child: Container(

          child: Center(
            child: Text(text)
          ),
          
        ),
      )


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Hover Effect Example')),
        body: Center(
          child: HoverButton(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HoverButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HoverButtonState createState() => _HoverButtonState();
}

class _HoverButtonState extends State<HoverButton> {
  bool _isHovered = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (_) {
        setState(() {
          _isHovered = true;
        });
      },
      onExit: (_) {
        setState(() {
          _isHovered = false;
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _isHovered ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Hover Over Me!',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


